Reading credentials from azure fails
I'm trying read azure default credentials but fails with following error
DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
04:54:12.161
lrr-data-service-perf-green-x
Attempted credentials:
   EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
   ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.
   SharedTokenCacheCredential: Shared token cache unavailable
   VisualStudioCodeCredential: Failed to get Azure user details from Visual Studio Code.
   AzureCliCredential: Azure CLI not found on path
   AzurePowerShellCredential: PowerShell is not installed

Can you help resolving the issue?
And this is how we get the creds.
def __prepare_postgre_db_url(cfg):
    postgres_server_resource_id = cfg["postgres_server_resource_id"]
    db = Vault.get_postgres_creds(postgres_server_resource_id)
    return (
        f"postgresql://{db['username']}:{db['password']}@{db['hostname']}:5432/postgres"
    )


__vault = DefaultAzureCredential() 
@staticmethod 
def get_postgres_creds(postgres_server_resource_id): 
 client = SecretClient( vault_url=f"https://{postgres_server_resource_id}.vault.azure.net", credential=Vault.__vault)


What are you trying to do here? Are you using something like this credential = DefaultAzureCredential()?

yes, this like this
__vault = DefaultAzureCredential()
@staticmethod
def get_postgres_creds(postgres_server_resource_id):
    client = SecretClient(
        vault_url=f"https://{postgres_server_resource_id}.vault.azure.net",
        credential=Vault.__vault,
    )


You need to configure environment variables and install azure cli.


Attempted credentials:EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.SharedTokenCacheCredential: Shared token cache unavailableVisualStudioCodeCredential: Failed to get Azure user details from Visual Studio Code.AzureCliCredential: Azure CLI not found on path AzurePowerShellCredential: PowerShell is not installed

The above error occurred due to  DefaultAzureCredential is failing to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Local environment variables are automatically used by the DefaultAzureCredential. It operates properly if these variables are set. if the environment variables is not set it will try to use ManagedIdentityCredential, SharedTokenCacheCredential, AzureCliCredential and VisualStudioCodeCredential.
You can create application and assign proper role to access the keyvault and you can fetch the AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET and set it in your environment for EnvironmentCredential authentication.
If you need access with user, download the azure cli using this MS-Document in your environment.
After download, login with az login command it will login with your username and password, fetch the azure credentials.
Command:
az login
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "72xxxx1db47",
    "id": "0caxxxx023324e1",
    "isDefault": true,
    "managedByTenants": [],
    "name": "<sub name>",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "72fxxx11db47",
    "user": {
      "name": "vxxxxm",
      "type": "user"
    }
  }


Now, I used the sample code to get the secret from azure key vault using DefaultAzureCredential
Code:
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
vault_name="venkatvault321"
vault_url = f"https://{vault_name}.vault.azure.net/"
client = SecretClient(vault_url=vault_url, credential=credential)
secret_name = "secret1"
secret = client.get_secret(secret_name)
print(secret.value)

Output
Welcome!!!


Reference:
Azure Identity client library for Python | Microsoft Learn
